# Jest test of Express API using MongoDB - runs on local machine, fails on CircleCI (Exceeded timeout)

Tags: typescript, mongodb, express, jestjs, circleci

Testing a RESTful API (written with Express in TypeScript) using Jest. The test runs successfully on my local machine (windows), but seems to timeout on CircleCI.

**.circleci/config.ylm**

```yaml
version: 2.1
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:16.3.0
    working_directory: ~/Mealplanr-api/api
    steps:
      - checkout:
          path: ~/Mealplanr-api
      - run:
          name: Install dependencies
          command: |
            yarn install
      - run:
          name: Run tests
          command: |
            yarn test:ci
      - store_test_results:
          path: test-results
      - store_artifacts:
          path: test-results
```

**package.json**

```json
...

"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --config nodemon.json src/server.ts",
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "test:ci": "jest"
  },

...
```

**jest.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
    roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],
    testMatch: [
        '**/__tests__/**/*.+(ts|tsx|js)',
        '**/?(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|tsx|js)',
    ],
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$': 'ts-jest',
    },
};
```

The test is as follows

**users.spec.ts**

```js
import request from 'supertest';
import app from '../app';

import { connectDB, closeDB } from '../connect';

describe('POST /users', () => {
    beforeAll(async () => {
        await connectDB();
    });

    afterAll(async () => {
        await closeDB();
    });

    it('Should create a new user', async () => {
        const res = await request(app).post('/users').send({
            email: 'test@test.test',
            password: '123456',
            passwordconfirmation: '123456',
        });

        const body = res.body;
        expect(body?.hasOwnProperty('_id')).toBe(true);
        expect(body?.hasOwnProperty('email')).toBe(true);
        expect(body?.hasOwnProperty('createdAt')).toBe(true);
        expect(body?.hasOwnProperty('updatedAt')).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

The connection functions in use are described here

**connect.ts**

```js
import { connect, disconnect } from 'mongoose';
import log from './logger';
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
import { Mockgoose } from 'mockgoose';
const mockgoose = new Mockgoose(mongoose);

const dbUri = process.env.DB_URI as string;

export async function connectDB() {
    if ((process.env.NODE_ENV as string) === 'test') {
        // In test environment, we don't want to connect to the real DB.
        await mockgoose.prepareStorage();
        await connect(dbUri, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useCreateIndex: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
        }).catch((error) => {
            log.error('Error in connecting', error);
        });
        log.info('Mock connection success');
    } else {
        // If not in test environment, connect to the database
        await connect(dbUri, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useCreateIndex: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
        }).catch((error) => {
            log.error('Error in connecting', error);
        });
        log.info('Connection success');
    }
}

export async function closeDB() {
    await mockgoose.shutdown();
    await disconnect();
}
```

**The output from CircleCI:**

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
yarn test:ci

yarn run v1.22.5
$ jest
Completed: 100 % (80.8mb / 80.8mbb FAIL  src/routes/users.spec.ts (30.653 s)
  ● POST /users › Should create a new user

    thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a hook.
    Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."

       5 |
       6 | describe('POST /users', () => {
    >  7 |  beforeAll(async () => {
         |  ^
       8 |      await connectDB();
       9 |  });
      10 |

      at src/routes/users.spec.ts:7:2
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/routes/users.spec.ts:6:1)
      at TestScheduler.scheduleTests (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:333:13)
      at runJest (node_modules/@jest/core/build/runJest.js:387:19)
      at _run10000 (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:408:7)
      at runCLI (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:261:3)


  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

      40 |
      41 | export async function closeDB() {
    > 42 |  await mockgoose.shutdown();
         |                  ^
      43 |  await disconnect();
      44 | }
      45 |

      at node_modules/mockgoose/built/mockgoose.js:55:54
      at Mockgoose.Object.<anonymous>.Mockgoose.shutdown (node_modules/mockgoose/built/mockgoose.js:50:16)
      at src/connect.ts:42:18
      at step (src/connect.ts:33:23)
      at Object.next (src/connect.ts:14:53)
      at src/connect.ts:8:71
      at Object.<anonymous>.__awaiter (src/connect.ts:4:12)
      at closeDB (src/connect.ts:99:12)
      at src/routes/users.spec.ts:12:16
      at step (src/routes/users.spec.ts:33:23)
      at Object.next (src/routes/users.spec.ts:14:53)
      at src/routes/users.spec.ts:8:71
      at Object.<anonymous>.__awaiter (src/routes/users.spec.ts:4:12)
      at src/routes/users.spec.ts:11:11

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        30.842 s
Ran all test suites.
Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Exited with code exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be, that mockgoose is deprecated, which results in it not working properly when running on CircleCI. A solution to this is using [mongodb-memory-server](https://github.com/nodkz/mongodb-memory-server#usage).

> [Warning: This package has been deprecated! Consider using mongodb-memory-server instead.](https://github.com/Mockgoose/Mockgoose#warning-this-package-has-been-deprecated-consider-using-mongodb-memory-server-instead)

This partially solves the problem. The only version I've currently gotten it to work with, was using the following in package.json:

```json
"config": {
    "mongodbMemoryServer": {
      "version": "4.2.3"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue recently with `"mongodb-memory-server": "^8.13.0"`. My solution was to use `node: bullseye` image (which is Debian 11 based) on CircleCI and it worked without requiring any extra config.

Here's a sample repo with it all working: https://github.com/duluca/document-ts